# QPainter drawText with fractional pointsizes

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter

Is there a way to draw text with fractional point sizes in Qt 5.
I'm trying to use `QFont::setPointSizeF()` but it doesn't seem to work on any platform I tried on (mac/linux/windows) and point size is always rounded.

`QFontDatabase::isScalable` and `QFontDatabase::isSmoothlyScalable` returns `true` for the font in all cases.

I tried setting various `QFont::fontHintingPreference` and `QPainter::RenderHint`.

I might be able to work around this using `QFont::setPixelSize` and `QPainter::scale`, but seem odd that `QFont::setPointSizeF` is broken?!

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Simple program that shows the problem:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget() : QWidget(0)
    {
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent */*e*/)
    {
        QPainter p(this);
        int y=10;

        for (qreal i = 10; i < 20; i += 0.2) {
            QFont font("Times"); // or any font font in the system
            font.setPointSizeF(i);
            p.setFont(font);
            p.drawText(1, y, QString("This should be point size %1 but is %2!").arg(font.pointSizeF()).arg(QFontInfo(font).pointSizeF()));
            y += i;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyWidget widget;
    widget.resize(400, 740);
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Same issue with qt4? Are you trying 5.1.1?

Comment: Tried Qt 4.8 briefly on Mac and more in Qt 5.1.1 on mac, linux and in windowes (for windows tried dl versions and even compiled version with directwrite support)

Comment: Is it getting better when you start using scale and setPixelSize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Qt calculates pixel size based on point size and that ends up at QFont::setPixelSize which takes int as parameter so it gets rounded (or something like that).

So to get better precision I can do something like:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*e*/)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    int y=10;

    for (qreal i = 10; i < 20; i += 0.2) {
        QFont font("Times"); // or any font
        font.setPointSizeF(i); // this has round to int error (on 72 dpi screen 10.2 would be rounded to 10 and 10.6 to 11.0 etc)
        p.setFont(font);

        qreal piX = i * p.device()->logicalDpiX() / 72.0;
        qreal piY = i * p.device()->logicalDpiY() / 72.0;
        qreal xscale = piX / qRound(piX);
        qreal yscale = piY / qRound(piY);

        //p.save();
        p.translate(1, y);
        p.scale(xscale, yscale);
        p.drawText(0, 0, QString("This should be point size %1 but is %2!").arg(font.pointSizeF()).arg(QFontInfo(font).pointSizeF() * xscale));
        p.resetTransform();
        //p.restore();
        y += i;
    }
}
```

I can get desired result this way.

Comment: Your question was not how to solve the issue, but whether what you used was wrong. You got an answer for that, didn't you? Why did you not mark it? What was the concern left?

Comment: my question started with "Is there a way to draw text with fractional point sizes in Qt 5"?

Comment: I do not know what it was anymore. You changed forth and back. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an unexpected behavior. See the lines below:

```
"This should be point size 10 but is 9.75!"
"This should be point size 10.2 but is 10.5!"
"This should be point size 10.4 but is 10.5!"
"This should be point size 10.6 but is 10.5!"
"This should be point size 10.8 but is 10.5!"
"This should be point size 11 but is 11.25!"
"This should be point size 11.2 but is 11.25!"
"This should be point size 11.4 but is 11.25!"
"This should be point size 11.6 but is 11.25!"
"This should be point size 11.8 but is 12!"
"This should be point size 12 but is 12!"
"This should be point size 12.2 but is 12!"
...
```

Then, check also the documentation:

`Sets the point size to pointSize. The point size must be greater than zero. The requested precision may not be achieved on all platforms.`

Comment: "The requested precision may not be achieved on all platforms." I tried on all 3 major platforms and it won't work on all of them, and all actually do support smooth font scaling (cocoa on mac, windows directwrite/cleartext...)

Comment: and as you see in your result it can and does set 10.5, why it wont accept 10.2 and other fractional values?!

Comment: This is normal, and this is how it is supposed to work as far as I can tell. Check the documentation again what it says. Also, there are many platforms, and you only tried three. I would say, this is OK.